# How do I SELECT multiple columns, but only show the results that are unique/non-duplicates (based on one specific column)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bit of an interesting table where two keys come together to make the primary key for each row. But in one edge case I want to SELECT all the rows (but only about 4 columns), but not have any duplicates of a specific column in the results.

So for example if I have a table with columns "account_id, company_id, key, is_customer, favorite_veg" there will be a lot of duplicate "account_id"s because they come together with "company_id" to form the primary key.

But what if I just want a list of all account_ids, but while keeping the other rows? Confusingly the other rows will be static between different company IDs in this example, so there's no potential risk of information being not included.

In my head it's something like "SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) COLUMNS (account_id, key, is_customer, favorite_veg) FROM customers" but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: If `DISTINCT ON` doesn't solve your problem, please add some sample data and expected output. Your problem seems to be not very complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `DISTINCT ON` helps? This gives out all rows with the first occurrence of a distinct `account_id`

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f9d3468576cd7ddd95e0f3a90463e715)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (account_id) 
    account_id, 
    key, 
    is_customer, 
    favorite_veg
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_id, key, is_customer, favorite_veg
FROM customers;
```

The `DISTINCT` applies to the entire row.  Based on your description, this might suffice.

If not, Postgres offers an extension, `DISTINCT ON`, which is used in conjunction with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (account_id) account_id, key, is_customer, favorite_veg
FROM customers
ORDER BY account_id;
```

When used like this, it guarantees a result set with one row per `account_id`.

You can add a second key after the `account_id` in the `ORDER BY` if you want to specify the earliest or latest or biggest or something else for the row being returned.